# Multiple callbacks on JS event

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener, themoviedb-api

I have a form with two inputs fields.

```
  <form action="file.js" method="post" class="FormData">
    <div>
        <p>Year</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="Year"></input>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Name</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="Tvshow"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
       <button class="btn">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

On the one hand Year field will obtain year chosen by user to show any tvshow and tvshow field will save tvshow name to show it base on moviedb Api request.

This is my javascript code:

```
const callbackYear = Year_User => 
{
    Year_User(Year);
}

const callbackTvshow = show => 
{
  show(name)
}

const getData = () => {
    const button = document.querySelector(".btn");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const Form = document.querySelector(".FormData");
        const Year = new FormData(Form).get("Year");
        const name = new FormData(Form).get("Tvshow");
        callbackYear(Year);
        callbackTvshow(name);
    });
}

callbackYear((Year_User) => 
{
  console.log(Year_User);
})

callbackTvshow((show) => 
{
  console.log(show);
})
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to get both data (Year and Tvshow name) with two severals callbacks called **Year_User** and **show** to make an statement between the two callbacks.

Something like this:

```
//Example
 callbackYear((Year_User) => 
 {
   if(Year_User!=undefined)
   {
     callbackTvshow((Tvshow) => 
     {
       //Code


     })
   }
 })
```

Maybe it could be more clearly now with this example.

Please help!

Comment: You have made a good start, but consider using a single listener on the parent form. See: [Can anyone please explain event delegation in JavaScript and how is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: Also, your "TV Show" input has the name `Tvshow` and **not** `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

seems that you put the wrong name to the Tv show property

The code:

```
    const Year = new FormData(Form).get("Year");
    const name = new FormData(Form).get("Name");
    alert(Year);
    alert(name);
```

Prints the "Year" and "null" cause "Name" is not a field name... The correct one would be "Tvshow"

```
  const Year = new FormData(Form).get("Year");
  const name = new FormData(Form).get("Tvshow");
  alert(Year);
  alert(name);
```

It outputs the Year and the name correctly.

**Edit:**

If I understood correctly after the updates the point is, you want to get different data (year and TV), but one data depends on the other so you want to execute a callback if, and only if, a condition is matched, as the example shows.

So, why instead of delegating this problem to 2 callbacks what if we had some extra functions to help us? We can create a "main" function and then do some logic there, we can get the data, we can process it, etc.

```
button.addEventListener('click', runScript);
function runScript() {
     const year = get Year

      if (year) {
        // doSomeCoolStuff with the tv show
      }
     }
```

By doing this is possible to create functions generic enough to be called all long the code, so if we want to process the tv show without caring about the year, if we do this approach correctly will be possible to do

```
processTvShow(...)
```

On the other hand, as the example, if we depend of the year, we can easily do

```
if (year) {
   processTvShow(...)
}
```

Comment: You are right, get back to callbacks you know how could I solve it?

Comment: Hi, honestly I am not sure if I truly understood the problem. Why you are using the callback to elements? Could you please provide more details about it? :)

Comment: I updated my post giving more details about it :)

Comment: I edit my answer to show some ideas, Idk if it's useful :p

Answer (score 0):

The above code is calling `getData` twice with one param.

But `getData` accepts two params at the same time:

```js
getData(
  (Year_User) => { console.log(Year_User) }, 
  (Tvshow) => { console.log(Tvshow) }
)
```

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for your answer it seems I explained bad, I'm gonna reedit my question